# Встретил код и у меня возник вопрос. Что значит generator = this, как это работает?

Tags: c#

```
{
  GetFibonacci_generator generator;

  if (state == -2 && initialThreadId == Environment.CurrentManagedThreadId)
  {
    state = 0;
    generator = this;
  }
  else
  {
    generator = new GetFibonacci_generator(0);
    generator.forThis = forThis;
  }

  generator.local_maxValue = param_maxValue;

  return generator;
}
```

Comment: Проверяется, является ли текущий поток основным и если да, то просто возвращается текущий объект, в противном случае создаётся новый.

Comment: @ori типа софтварная реализация `[ThreadStatic]`?